# How create matrix dynamic using PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Can any one help me? I found difficult about create matrix dynamic using PHP programming. I want value of matrix dynamic from mysql database.

Such as example :

```
INF 56  78  67
45  INF 78  67
45  56  INF 67
45  56  78  INF
```

This code it :

```
function    random()
{
    $max = 7;
    if (isset($_POST['amount']))
    {
        $amount = (int)$_POST['amount'];
        $rows = ($amount > 2 && $amount < 15) ? $amount : 3;
    }
    else
    {
        $rows = rand(3, 7);
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++)
    {
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $rows; $j++)
        {
            $this->table[$i][$j] = $i == $j ? INF : rand(0, 99);
        }
    }
}


function    __toString()
{
    $str = '<table class="table table-bordered" id="tableInput"><tbody>';
    $str .= '<tr><td></td>';
    foreach ($this->table as $rowName => $row)
    {
        $str .= "<td>$rowName</td>";
    }
    $str .= '</tr>';
    foreach ($this->table as $rowName => $row)
    {
        $str .= "<tr><td>$rowName</td>";
        foreach ($row as $columnName => $value)
        {
            $str .= "<td>";
            $str .=
                '<input class="form-control" type="text" value="' . $value . '" name="table[' . $rowName . '][' .
                $columnName . ']" requied' . ($columnName == $rowName ? ' disabled' : '') . '>';
            $str .= "</td>";
        }
        $str .= '</tr>';
    }
    $str .= '</tbody></table>';
    return $str;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do  you want? Do you want to store it? do you want to retrieve it? Either way I would go with a json object stored in a text field in your db, or maybe varchar255 if it doesnt get bigger than this. but please clarify what you want to do with the matrix.

Comment: I want to find the shortest distance using BranchAndBound algorithm . One of the calculation using the matrix . I want the value of the matrix is taken from a mysql database table (dynamic matrix) . The database value entered by the user .

Comment: upgrade your question with the specifics of what you want.

Comment: i'm sorry.. I want to display this matrix, but value of matrix taken from mysql. So, result such as :INF 56  78  67
45  INF 78  67
45  56  INF 67
45  56  78  INF

Comment: as i said. edit your question, add this information in your question. 3 steps:  what is your problem? what do you want as end result? what hae you tried so far.

Comment: This is my table temp_hasil: 
"id_temp" "id"
"86"          "45"
"87"          "56"
"88"          "78"
"89"          "67"
 i want end result such as :
INF 56  78  67
45  INF 78  67
45  56  INF 67
45  56  78  INF